# Try to send a csv file but the permission fails

Tags: java, android, sendfile

I'm trying to send a file (Intent.ACTION_SEND) but when I use for example gmail, the permission fail, and gmail notify me the permission of the attached file don't permit send it. 
Here is my code:

```
private void LoadSendFile() {

    String temp = new String();
    File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Datos" + ext);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

        for (ActivityMat data : matriculas) {
            if (!data.getViajesConductor().isEmpty()) {
                for (String date : data.getViajesConductor()) {
                    temp += data.getName() + ": " + date + "\n";
                    fos.write(temp.getBytes());
                    Log.e("Write File: ", temp);
                }
            }
        }

        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("Creando fichero: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not found ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Escribiendo fichero: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can not build the file ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(tempFile));
    sendIntent.setType("application/csv");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

(Excuse my language, I'm not English)

UPDATE:
The code had been updated. Now I have permission, but gmail notify me that it can't send an empty file, but I know (because I write a log message when I write in the file (Datos.csv)) that I write in the file. Any idea??
Here is the log (I saw is a problem of permission):

```
E/Creando fichero:: /storage/emulated/0/Datos.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Datos.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 ....  //here the "at" statement

Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`. Try `Context.WORLD_READABLE`.

Comment: You have two catch blocks. Are they used? Look in the logcat.  You should display a toast telling the user so. And then return. Please adapt your code and try. Then adapt the code here to show what you did.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see it, I update it.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: `but gmail notify me that it can't send an empty file`. You should not call that intent when you have an exception. Put return statements in those catch blocks. And display a toast to the user before the return. This is the second time i tell you. Adapt your code!

Comment: Oh sorry, update the code with the toast.

Comment: `"File not found ..."`. Bad info. Bad toast. Inform the user better replace by `"FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFilesDir()` is private internal memory for your app. The email app has no acces to it.

Try another location like `getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Moreover you need to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in manifest file.

And if compiling for Android 6 and above request at runtime permission from the user for that.

Comment: I update the code and explain the new problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes, I added the permission before, but the problem persist.

Comment: Did you read all? You should ask gor runtime permission too when >= 6.0. You are not even reacting.

Comment: Yes, I was doing the runtime request. All right now. Thanks a lot for your help and your patience.